# How do I write a script correctly for GSheets that copy and pastes different ranges without errors?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, copy-paste

I have a script that works well to copy and paste a range from example Sheet1 range: `A1:C200` to Sheet2 range: `A1:C200`. My problem is my rows constantly vary from 200 - 3000 rows depending on the data I have imported daily into my spreadsheet and at the moment I'm constantly having to manually write each range.

Is it possible to write a script that would adapt to a variable range of rows each time and copy an entire range from columns `A,B,C` to the last row of available data like the  range formula:  `A1:C`?
See script example.

Original Script: (works)

```
function copy() {  
  var OriginalRange=SpreadsheetApp.openById('Spreadsheet ID').getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange("A1:C200");
  var DestinationRange=SpreadsheetApp.openById('Spreadsheet ID').getSheetByName('Sheet2').getRange("A1:C200");
DestinationRange.setValues(OriginalRange.getValues());

}
```

Ideal variable range Script: (exception: does not match the number of rows errors)

```
function copy() {  
  var OriginalRange=SpreadsheetApp.openById('Spreadsheet ID').getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange("A1:C");
  var DestinationRange=SpreadsheetApp.openById('Spreadsheet ID').getSheetByName('Sheet2').getRange("A1:C");
DestinationRange.setValues(OriginalRange.getValues());

}
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17637159/1907765) has a pretty neat way of getting the last row from a given column. From there all you need to do is grab the reference of that row and use it to get the range you want to select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow) to get the last row with content. You just need to restructure the code a little bit:

```
function copy() {  
  var OriginalSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Spreadsheet ID').getSheetByName('Sheet1')
  var OriginalRange=OriginalSheet.getRange("A1:C"+OriginalSheet.getLastRow());
  var DestinationSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Spreadsheet ID').getSheetByName('Sheet2')
  var DestinationRange=DestinationSheet.getRange("A1:C"+OriginalSheet.getLastRow());
  DestinationRange.setValues(OriginalRange.getValues());
}
```

**Careful:**

This approach will only work if in the range the last row with content is indeed within the columns `A:C`.